# ostream .open function not existing (C++)

Tags: c++, fstream

So I'm new to programming and I'm following a tutorial and I got to fstream, but I don't know if my compiler is acting weirdly or I'm missing a file or something but the .open function does not seem to work and fstream is acting weirdly. (Like you cannot use (ostreamobject)("test.txt"); I'm new to programming so please don't use technical terms.

I've searched around a bit but I didn't find anything.

I don't know what's wrong with my code or my compiler but outputFile.open does not exist weirdly enough. I'm using visual studio 2015. This is a small amount of code I wrote and it still comes with an error. Here's the code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
ostream oFile;
istream iFile;

oFile.open("test.txt");

    return 0;
}
```

Here's the error codes:

1>d:\dokument\visual studio 2015\projects\fstream\fstream\fstream.cpp(13): error C2512: 'std::basic_ostream>': no appropriate default constructor available
1>  d:\programmering\vc\include\iosfwd(679): note: see declaration of 'std::basic_ostream>'
1>d:\dokument\visual studio 2015\projects\fstream\fstream\fstream.cpp(14): error C2512: 'std::basic_istream>': no appropriate default constructor available
1>  d:\programmering\vc\include\iosfwd(678): note: see declaration of 'std::basic_istream>'
1>d:\dokument\visual studio 2015\projects\fstream\fstream\fstream.cpp(16): error C2039: 'open': is not a member of 'std::basic_ostream>'
1>  d:\programmering\vc\include\iosfwd(679): note: see declaration of 'std::basic_ostream>'
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Answer (score 3):

The problem is, that you are using "ostream" and "istream" instead of "o**f**stream" and "i**f**stream" (note the "**f**" for "**f**ile").

Use this version:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
// #include <iostream> // you don't need this and it caused most of your confusion!
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   ofstream oFile;
   ifstream iFile;

   oFile.open("test.txt");

   return 0;
}
```

FYI: 
"ofstream" and "ifstream" are both superclasses of "ostream" and "istream". They provide further functions (like "open") for interacting with files

Comment: Thank you sooo much, I'm clumbsy :D

Answer (score 1):

Well, it *doesn't* exist. There is no `ostream` constructor that takes a filename.

**You meant `ofstream`.**

You could have checked this out by simply visiting the documentation.

If your tutorial really says `ostream`, tell us what it is and stop using it.
You should learn C++ from [a good book](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/560648), not from random "tuts" on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Consider declaring oFile and iFile as concrete files.

```
ofstream oFile;
ifstream iFile;
```